# Color coding Modified Date

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm looking to color code the Modified  column in Microsoft Lists. I know I need to use JSON but unsure of the code.

I would like it to be green if less than or equal to 30 days, orange/Amber if between 31 and 45, and red if greater than 45.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using JSON column formatting for Modified column with this JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField < addDays(@now,-45), 'red', if(@currentField < addDays(@now,-30),'orange','green'))"
  },
  "txtContent": "=@currentField"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

You can change the `style` as per your requirements based on similar conditions given in above JSON.

Example:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "color": "white",
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField < addDays(@now,-45), 'red', if(@currentField < addDays(@now,-30),'orange','green'))",
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "padding-left": "10px"
  },
  "txtContent": "=@currentField"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)